# Error: Could not start the command: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "bare_conf".tex

Tags: texstudio

I am getting this error on tex studio, firstly I was using 2.0 of texStudio, now I updated my tex studio version but still, the problem exists. If I open any latex project then getting this error on compilation time. Kindly help me to get rid of this error.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you install the TeX editor *after* the distribution?

Comment: I was using 2.1 something version now I'm using TexStudio 3.0.1 after uninstalling the old version, but still, problems exist

Comment: What's your OS, and your distribution?